# Assembly Basics: Output register value

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

I just started learning assembly language and I am already stuck on the part to "display the decimal values stored in a register on the screen". Im using the emu8086, any help would be appreciated! :)

```
.model small  ;Specifies the memory model used for program to identify the size of code and data segments

org 100h      ;allocate 100H memory locations for stack

.data         ;the segment of the memory to declare/initialze the variables

var1 db 0006
var2 db 0002
var3 db 0001


.code           ;start of the code segment

main proc       ;start of the first procedure

mov bl, var1
add bl, var2
add bl, var3


mov ah, 00h   ; display  function here?
mov dl, bl    ; output the bl register's value?  
int 21h

mov ah, 4ch  ;exit DOS function                                           
int 21h

endp         ;end of the first procedure

end main     ;end of the complete assembly program

ret
```

Comment: @MichaelPetch I tried that but failed to understand. Im looking for a simple and easy to grasp answer! :(

Comment: @MichaelPetch So I cant print the register value without converting it into a string first? Even if it is in hexadecimal, binary or any other base? I do understand the way to convert it by remainder, just wanted to know if there is any other way? All I want is to display the value inside the register on the screen!

Comment: Integers in registers or memory are always in binary, no matter how you write the source code.  e.g. `0Fh` and `15` assemble to the same bit pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> mov ah, 00h   ; display  function here?
> ```

No, the single-char display function is at [AH=2 / `int 21h`](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02)

Since your BL register contains only a small value (9) all it would have taken was:

```
mov  ah, 02h
mov  dl, bl
add  dl, "0"   ; Integer to single-digit ASCII character
int  21h
```

If values become a bit bigger but not exceeding 99 you can get by with:

```
mov  al, bl       ; [0,99]
aam               ; divide by 10: quotient in ah, remainder in al (opposite of DIV)
add  ax, "00"
xchg al, ah
mov  dx, ax
mov  ah, 02h
int  21h
mov  dl, dh
int  21h
```

A solution that doesn't use the `AAM` instruction:

```
mov  al, bl       ; [0,99]
cbw               ; Same result as 'mov ah, 0' in this case
mov  dl, 10
div  dl           ; Divides AX by 10: quotient in al, remainder in ah
add  ax, "00"
mov  dx, ax
mov  ah, 02h
int  21h
mov  dl, dh
int  21h
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got : 'aam' not supported in 64 bits mode

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL The post addresses the emu8086 environment where the `AAM` instruction should work. Nonetheless I've added a version of the calculation that does not use `AAM`.

Answer (score 2):

In emu8086 you can use a ready-made macro and procedure for that purpose.

Example:

```
include 'emu8086.inc'       ; Include useful macros and procedures

.model small

.stack

.data

var1 db 6
var2 db 2
var3 db 7

.code

DEFINE_PRINT_NUM         ; Create procedure PRINT_NUM          
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS     ; Create procedure PRINT_NUM_UNS

crlf proc
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, 13
    int 21h
    mov dl, 10
    int 21h
    ret
crlf endp

main proc

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; test output: 54321 & -11215 
    mov ax, 54321
    call PRINT_NUM_UNS   ; Print AX as unsigned number
    call crlf
    mov ax, 54321
    call PRINT_NUM       ; Print AX as signed number
    call crlf

    mov bl, var1
    add bl, var2
    add bl, var3

    mov ax, bx           ; AX contains the number for PRINT_NUM
    xor ah, ah           ; Could contain crap
    call PRINT_NUM
    call crlf

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

main endp

end main
```